# GNUplot add OSX system font to PDF output

Tags: gnuplot

I need to use a symbol font called Moon Fonts TTF in the PDF output from GNUplot. GNUplot finds it with no problem in the Aqua terminal.

I've tried:

> set fontpath "/Users/house/Library/Fonts/MoonPhases.ttf"

and other add fontfile suggestions from the gnuplot help pages with no luck.

I have also tried a series of .ttf, .otf, postscript and unicode-mapped fonts with some support from a typography expert, with no luck at all: pdfcairo, postscript or epscairo cannot seem to find it.

GNUplot's 'show fontpath' gives:

> system fontpath is "/System/Library/Fonts" "/Library/Fonts" "/Users/house/Library/Fonts"

and the fonts are there in one of those paths. I also tried placing them directly in GN's working directory.

If anyone has suggestions about how to make this work it would be much appreciated.

OSX Snow Leopard
GNUplot 4.6.2

Comment: See this SO post for how I eventually solved this:

[Solution to this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900030/gnuplot-unicode-characters/21024985#21024985

Answer (score 1):

You could first use the postscript eps terminal to plot, and then convert the eps to postscript using `epstopdf` which, at least on my system, embeds the needed fonts into the resulting pdf. If it doesn't you can try to force it by providing the ghostscript parameter directly.

To make your font visible for the postscript terminal, install it into your fontpath and then use

```
fc-cache -fv
```

to reload your font cache. The name of the font might vary, because for postscript you have to find the postscript name of the font:

```
fc-query /path/to/your/font/MoonPhases.ttf | grep postscript
```

For more examples of this, read this Blogpost:

[Schriftarten über Umwege: Gnuplot unter Linux und Mac OS X](https://techblog.auf-nach-mallorca.info/2014/03/12/schriftarten-ber-umwege-gnuplot-unter-linux-und-mac-os-x/)

It is in german language, but google Translate should help.